# Linear regression with variables which are possibly dependent to each other

Tags: r, regression

I am working on building a linear regression model with one response variable and multiple explanatory variables. For the explanatory variables, I suspect that one numerical variable and one factor variable are dependent to each other. Here I have two questions:
First, how can I test whether they are dependent or independent? I know a bit about chi-square test for independence but in R, it seems that I can only test for two numerical variables or two factor variables.

Second, how should I build the model given that these two variables are dependent to some extent? My goal is to explain the variance of the response variable. Am I able to tell which variable explains a larger part of the response variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Complete linear dependency between two variables is very simple to test:

```
if( cor(v1,v2) != 1 ) { print("v1 is not linearly dependent on v2"}
```

It's extremely unlikely that a factor variable and a continuous numerical variable would meet this test. In R doing this test on the "naked" variable would throw an error:

```
cor( factor(rep(1:2,5)), 1:10)
#Error in cor(factor(rep(1:2, 5)), 1:10) : 'x' must be numeric
cor( as.numeric(factor(rep(1:2,5))), 1:10)
#[1] 0.1740777
```

However the use of two such variables in a regression framework would not throw an error or result in  exclusion of coefficient clculation.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider doing a VIF (variable inflation factor) with you independent variables. If the VIF for an independent variable is > 10, then the other predictors (independent variables) do a good job at predicting that independent variable and you should probably remove it if you are concerned about your regression coefficient estimates.

[This link](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/39-regression-model-diagnostics/160-multicollinearity-essentials-and-vif-in-r/) has a good explanation along with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the suggestion above about computing the Variance Inflation Factor. The general rule of thumb is any VIF greater than 10 signifies a high correlation between your independent variables. However, this may change on a case to case basis and depending on where you use it. I believe the next best approach is to do a Principal Component Analysis of your highly correlated variables. By doing principal component analysis, you project the two variables into a new single variable that explains the maximum variation from the two highly correlated ones. However, this will also affect the interpretation of the new variable created as its a projection of two highly correlated variables.

Answer (score 0):

The VIF feature as mentioned by others is a very easy method and widely used for the same reasons.

https://github.com/VishweshDeore/Data-Science-R/tree/master/R/Linear%20Regression

You can refer to the code in the above example to understand how you can execute it.

Answer (score 0):

As almost everyone else has said, the VIF scores can be helpful in diagnosing problematic variables. You can find suggested cutoffs in extant literature, though they vary slightly (like all arbitrary cut points in statistics). You can use the `vif()` function from the `car` package, which takes as input your fitted model. It will give a VIF score for each predictor, and whether or not it is above or below 10, if you see any that you think might be problematic, it's worth a shot to remove them from the model and see if you lose much information.

There are a lot of methods for comparing models during this process (AIC, BIC, log likelihood), but I prefer to compare *Adjusted* R<sup>2</sup> values between models. You'll see a decrease in regular R<sup>2</sup> when you remove a collinear variable, but you might actually see an increase in Adjusted R<sup>2</sup>, because you have made your model more parsimonious.

One final thing I would like to add is that regression is fairly robust to high collinearity among predictors. It is certainly less of an issue than heteroscedasticity of errors. So unless they are correlated at above .9 or so, you're probably okay keeping both variables in the model if they are both valuable predictors of your DV